# Python: starting threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to start different threads inside a python script.

```
class MyThread (threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, sf):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sf = sf

    def run (self):
        # opening files
```

I append the different threads to a threadlist

```
while True:
    path_to_file = L.pop()
    tr = MyThread(path_to_file) 
    tr.start()
    threadlist.append(tr)



for elem in threadlist:
    print(elem._name)
    print(elem.isAlive())

answer = input("Another thread to start? ")
if answer is not 'y':
    break
```

Printing out the alive state of every thread shows that the previously started ones get stopped:

```
Thread-1
True
Another thread to start? y
Thread-1
False
Thread-2
True
Another thread to start? y
Thread-1
False
Thread-2
False
Thread-3
True
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a reason you've created a subclass of a `threading.Thread` instead of doing `threading.Thread(target=your_func, args=(param1, param2, ...)`?

Comment: Your `MyThread` class doesn't take any arguments, yet you are giving it `path_to_file`.

Comment: @msvalcon: Not really, it's just something I copied from some tutorial. Would you suggest this as be a better solution?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but don't compare strings with `is` - you want object equality, not object identity.

Comment: @ijon-thicy unless you *really* need to subclass something, avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell why your threads are stopped, because you have not shown what is in your `run` method.

As others have mentioned, it is not clear why you are extending the `Thread` class.

However, here is one working example of how you might make the class above exhibit multiple living threads. Bear in mind that threading in Python will not buy you CPU parallelism, because of the Global Interpreter Lock. However, as noted in the comment below, it can buy you performance if your application is IO-bound.

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class MyThread (Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run (self):
       time.sleep(1)
        # opening files

threadlist = []
for i in range(3):
  tr = MyThread() 
  tr.start()
  threadlist.append(tr)

for elem in threadlist:
    print(elem.isAlive())
```

Comment: Your statement about performance is incorrect. Blocking I/O happens outside the GIL so you can get performance improvements in I/O-bound code using only the `threading` library.

Comment: @ebarr, I was thinking of CPU parallelism. I will update this.